# How to define the control sequence sent by CTRL-Delete if it is unknown so far?

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I am using `bash` connected through SSH to a server that I do not control, and since I didn't have the bindings for `CTRL-Backspace` to delete the word to the left, and `CTRL-Delete` to delete the word to the right, I set out to change that.
I found countless posts as to how to do it, and why it was a complex issue, which helped me solve what seems to be the most common case: `CTRL-Backspace`.

I copied `/etc/inputrc` into `~/.inputrc` and added

```
"\C-?": backward-kill-word
```

That did the trick. (I figured that out by using `CTRL-V` and then `CTRL-Backspace` which produces `^?`).

Now the problem and the crux of the question which I haven't found addressed anywhere yet, is **what to do if a key pressing, here in my case CTRL-Delete, does not produce (or does not seem to produce) a control sequence**: indeed `CTRL-V` and then `CTRL-Delete` shows nothing.
I tried `showkey -a` to find the same result (whereas it produces the `^?` for CTRL-Backspace as expected, and `Backspace` is `^H`, and `Delete` is `^[[3~`).

I tried to add `"\C-\e[3~": kill-word` to `.inputrc` (in the hopes that it would do `CTRL` and then `Delete`, since `Delete` is `^[[3~`), but that is probably not how `readline` can interpret the `.inputrc`, and that did not work.

Is there a way for these key pressings to do anything, or is there no hope, and if that is the case, why?

Comment: `"\C-[3~"` is omitting the *escape* character, which bash could show as `\e`

Comment: I actually have also tried `"\C-\e[3~": kill-word` to no avail. I feel like the fact that CTRL-Delete produces no control sequence is the real problem here.

Comment: In xterm, I see `^[[3;5~` which would be `\e[3;5~`, not `\C-\e[3~`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I found in several other posts, but this is not the case in this terminal somehow (since I see no output when I type CTRL-Delete in `showkey -a`). Is there a way for me to figure out why/what is the actual sequence? (I tried adding `"\e[3;5~": kill-word` in the `.inputrc` just in case, to no avail again). Edit.: to be clear, I had tried `"\C-\e[3~"` in the hopes that it would do `CTRL` and then `Delete`, since `Delete` is `^[[3~`, but that is probably not how `readline` can interpret the `.inputrc`.

Comment: I edited my initial post to clarify why I had tried `"\C-\e[3~"`.